# Need assistance creating a specific regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

I am not so familiar with regular expressions and need some help creating one.
I need to create a regular expression that would filter any combination of '+'s and '-'s from a string.

For example :
if given "95--45++12-+45+-+7" it would output : ['--', '++', '-+', '+-+']

Help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r'[+-]+', yourtext)
```

results:

```
['--', '++', '-+', '+-+']
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: Weird how people like to downvote correct answers. Glad to help.

Comment: Not a downvoter but this is a bad question and answering it only encourages user to post more of those bad questions.

Comment: @Wombatz the question should be downvoted. The answer as I see it is helpful. I wouldn't downvote it. It only helps.